# IE8 execCommand insertorderedlist ignores BR elements

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, dojo, selection, execcommand

Using a command like:

`this.document.execCommand("insertorderedlist", false, argument);`

In most browsers works correctly, however, in IE (including IE9), it includes too much text.

So, for instance, say you have the following text in a ContentEditable div, with the caret located as specified (html included for structure):

```
test<br>
<br>[caret]
test2
```

And you then execute the execCommant, you end up with a bullet point at the the very beginning, and everything is indented as part of that bullet.

Like So:

```
<ol>
<li> test<br>
  <br>[caret]
  test2
</ol>
```

Which is to say, IE is including surrounding text that is only separated by a `<br>`.  It works correctly if there is container elements (div or span).

Comment: Faulty inference. I suggest you read about DOM Range and what `startContainer`, `endContainer` (note these may be elements or text nodes), `startOffset` and `endOffset` actually mean. MDN would be good starting point: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Range

Comment: I see what you are saying, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the only real solution is to not use `<br>` to separate lines.  Instead using `<div>` or `<p>`.